# Me salta Invalid Syntax Python

Tags: python

Al correr:

```py
pisos = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de pisos a imprimir"))
pisos += 1
for i in range(1,pisos,-1):
    for j in range(i):
        print("*", end="")
    print("\n")
```

Me salta el Invalid Syntax Python en la linea `print("*", end="")`.

Comment: Considerando la estructura de range: `range(start, stop, step)`

Has puesto `range(1, pisos, -1)`, suponiendo que pisos es un entero positivo, este bucle lanzaría un error ya que estaría mal definido...

Answer (score 0):

En python dependiendo de la versión generalmente para imprimir de forma concatenada se utiliza el símbolo +, para cuestiones sencillas, el error sintáctico se debe a una asignación directa en el print, podrías intentar esto:

```
print("*"+end+"") este seria el caso si tuvieras `end` definido en otra parte del código
```

o simplemente `print("*"+"")` si end es la asignación que tu le diste (cadena vacía), por otro lado, viendo la forma en la que diste el print, se puede tomar en cuenta que usaste una estructura para cadenas en formato, viéndolo como método de cadenas de python ".format"

en ese caso podrías intentar usar la siguiente estructura

```
print("{stra}{end}".format(stra = "*", end=""))
```

te recomendaría si eres nuevo en python checar documentaciones en paginas oficiales de python o paginas educativas que tengan ejemplos didácticos como este https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp
que tiene ejemplos para métodos en este caso para Strings (cadenas), inclusive podrás encontrar formas alternativas de impresión o ya con el tiempo llevar a cabo otra solución a problemas que aparezcan, con estos métodos.

por otro lado quizá el for como ya mencionaron este mal definido, ya que es `(start_Value, end_value, step)`, considerando que no hay pisos negativos claro (entrada positiva), en otro caso habría que invertir pisos y el 1.

```
for i in range(pisos,1,-1): esto ya dependería de tu problema a tratar y como se haya definido, esto es como un extra.
```

buenas noches.

Comment: para una sintaxis más *bonita* se puede usar los *f-strings*